Compton cross-section measure, 0 degrees
We are a group of undergraduate students currently doing a lab work to measure the Compton Cross-section, using a radioactive ${}^{22}$Na source.
The setup simply has the ${}^{22}$Na source decaying $\beta$ which sends 2 photons at opposite directions. One photon is captured by a gate detector and the other one interacts with an Aluminum target, we then place a detector at a certain angle $\theta$ to measure the energy spectrum of the outgoing photon.
The experimental cross section is measured via:
$$ \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} = \frac{1}{\Delta \Omega} \frac{N_S}{N_I} \frac{1}{\mathcal{N} dx} $$
where $N_S$ are the counts in the detector for the scattered photons and $N_I$ are the incident photons (aka the number of times the gate detector "is opened").
In addition $\mathcal{N} =N_{A}  \frac{\rho}{M}$ and $dx$ is the target's thickness.
For values of $\theta$ = 30,45,60,90 we get decent results, however when evaluating the spectrum for $\theta=0$ we get a result $10^2$ higher. (meaning the parameters outside of $N_S/N_I$ are decent).
The underlying suggestion is that there are additional counts in the spectrum ($N_S$ must be "too high").
Questions:
Is there actually a point in measuring the cross section at 0 degrees? If so, how do we evaluate the additional counts we should not be expecting?
If there is no point in using counts how do we evaluate experimentally the cross section at 0 deg?
The first thought we had (likely not a good one) was that the additional counts come from photons that are able to pass through the target without interacting , which could be evaluated via $I(t) = I_0 e^{-\mu dx}$: but the idea of a cross section at 0 degress is that the particles don't interact at all, right?

As a general comment, obtaining results that don't agree with expectations is more interesting.  I'm not suggesting that you've discovered new physics, but the process of systematically attempting to determine the explanation(s) seems like a valuable exercise.
